# p-adic Hecke operators in the Iwahori-Hecke algebra $C_c(J\backslash G(F)/J)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, hecke-algebras, p-adic, hecke-operators, affine-hecke-algebras

$\DeclareMathOperator\ch{ch}$Let $F$ be a non-archimedean local field, $\mathcal{O}$ its ring of integers, $\mathfrak{p}$ its maximal ideal and $\pi$ a uniformizer. I shall use $\kappa(F)$ to denote the residue field of $F$.

Let further $G = \mathrm{GL}_n$ denote the standard algebraic group scheme of the general linear group. Further I shall denote by

- $T$ : The standard split torus of $G$ consisting of diagonal matrices,
- $B$ : the standard Borel subgroup of $G$ of upper-triangular matrices with non-zero elements on the diagonal,
- $U$ : the standard unipotent subgroup of $G$ of upper-triangular matrices with $1$'s on the diagonal principal. Hence $B = TU$. I will also use $U^{-}$ for the subgroup of lower-diagonal matrices with $1$'s on its diagonal principal.

The roots and the Bruhat order are chosen in a standard way, i.e. all roots $\alpha_{ij}$ shall be positive iff $i > j$ and negative otherwise. For my needs, I realize the Weyl-Group $W = W(G(F),T(F))$ inside $G(\mathcal{O})$ by dropping the modulo $T(\mathcal{O})$-condition (this won't have any effect in my setting).

The **Iwahori subgroup** J of $G(F)$ is defined as the preimage of $B(\kappa(F))$ under the canonical projection $G(\mathcal{O}) \to G(\kappa(F))$. In other words
$$
J = \begin{pmatrix}
        \mathcal{O}^{\times} & \mathcal{O} & \ldots & \mathcal{O} \\
        \mathfrak{p} & \mathcal{O}^{\times} & \ddots & \vdots \\
        \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \mathcal{O} \\
        \mathfrak{p} & \ldots & \mathfrak{p} & \mathcal{O}^{\times}
    \end{pmatrix}.
$$
The Iwahori subgroup may be decomposed as the direct product
$$
J = U^{-}(\mathfrak{p})T(\mathcal{O})U(\mathcal{O}).
$$
The **(Iwahori-)Hecke algebra** $\mathcal{H}$ is the space of $\mathbb{C}$-valued functions on $G(F)$, that are

1. *Iwahori-bi-invariant*, i.e. $f(jgj') = f(g)$ for $j,j' \in J$ and $g \in G(F)$.
2. compactly supported
3. smooth, i.e. locally constant.

It is a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra under the convolution product given by
$$
(f \ast g)(x) = \int_{G(F)} f(xy^{-1})g(y)dy,
$$
where the Haar measure on $G(F)$ is chosen such that $vol(J,dg)=1$.

It is known, that as complex vector spaces,
$$
\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{H}_W \otimes X_{*}(T(F)),
$$
where $\mathcal{H}_W$ is the Hecke-algebra of $W$ (not necessary here) and $X_{*}(T(F))$ is the (commutative) group of rational cocharacters of $F$ (these are rational homomorphisms $F^{\times} \to T(F)/T(\mathcal{O})$. The cocharacter group $X_{*}(T(F))$ is known to be a free abelian group of rank n, and since I can drop the 'modulo $T(\mathcal{O})$'-condition, I will simply write
$$
\pi^{\lambda} = \begin{pmatrix}
        \pi^{\lambda_1} & &  \\
& \ddots & \\
        & & \pi^{\lambda_n}
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
for the image of $\pi$ under some $\lambda \in X_{*}(T(F))$.

The group of cocharacters can be realized inside $\mathcal{H}$ as follows: for a dominant $\lambda\in X_{*}(T(F))$ one defines the Hecke operator
$$
T_{\lambda} := \ch(J\pi^{\lambda}J),
$$
where by $\ch(\cdot)$ I mean the characteristic function of $\cdot$. As far as I understand it, if $\lambda\in X_{*}(T(F))$ is *any* (!) cocharacter, there are dominant $\lambda', \lambda'' \in  X_{*}(T(F))$ s.t. $\lambda = \lambda' - \lambda''$ and one defines
$$
\widetilde{T}_{\lambda} := T_{\lambda'} T^{-1}_{\lambda''}. 
$$
The definition should be independent on the choice of $\lambda'$ and $\lambda''$.

**Question:** I was wondering if there is any nice description of these $T^{-1}_{\lambda''}$, maybe any reference?

**Example:** I computed it in the simplest case when $n=2$ and $\lambda = (1,0)$ is the fundamental coweight. I got something like
$$
T^{-1}_{(1,0)} = \frac{1}{q} \ch(J\pi^{-(1,0)}J) - \frac{1}{q(q-1)} \ch(J
        w_2J),
$$
where $w_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
        & 1\\
1 &
    \end{pmatrix}$ is the (only) simple root.

Comment: In general, $T_g$ is **defined** to be $\textrm{ch}(JgJ)$; the expression you've written (with $T_{\lambda'}T_{\lambda''}^{-1}$) is how one defines the Bernstein basis of the Bernstein subalgebra.  In any event, one way to write down $T_\lambda^{-1}$ is using the element $T_{-\lambda}^*$ and a reduced expression for $\pi^\lambda$ in the extended affine Weyl group of $G$.  For a reference, see Proposition 4.13(1) in this article of Vigneras:

https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3484112

Comment: hi @krl, first of all thanks for you reply.
Thanks for your hint on the definition of a (general) $T_{\lambda}$, I have now modified it and put a tilde on it, but it is not really relevant now.
I have taken a look at the paper.. I don't know if we understand each other. The element $T*_{-\lambda}$ is defined using $T^{-1}_{\lambda}$, so as I see it, this would be just running in a circle. I also didn't understand what exactly you mean with "reduced expression" for $\pi^{\lambda}$?

Comment: In the paper of Vigneras, $T_{-\lambda}^*$ is defined as $T_u T_{s_r^{-1}}^*\cdots T_{s_1^{-1}}^*$, where $T_{s_i^{-1}}^* = T_{s_i^{-1}} - c_{s_i^{-1}}$ (notation of that Lemma 4.12), and where $s_1 s_2 \cdots s_r u$ is a reduced expression for $\pi^\lambda$.  In particular, you can define $T_{-\lambda}^*$ without inverses.  (Since you are working with with the Iwahori-Hecke algebra, some of these expressions will simplify.) Proposition 4.13(1) of the article then shows that $T_\lambda^{-1} = q_{\lambda}^{-1}T_{-\lambda}^*$.

Comment: As for defining a reduced expression, I would recommend reading a bit more about (extended) affine Weyl groups, and working out the example of $\textrm{GL}_n(F)$.  For example, if $\lambda = (1,0)$, then a reduced expression is $\pi^\lambda = \begin{pmatrix} \pi & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ \pi & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.  The first element is a simple reflection ($s_1$ above), and the second element has length 0 and is contained in $\Omega$ ($u$ above).

Comment: I would ask you maybe some questions if I got it correct.. 
1) Vigneras works with the Iwahori-Matsumoto (IM) presentation, and so, in order to invert $T_{\lambda}$, I need to make the conversion from the Bernstein-Zelevinsky (BZ) presentation to the IM-presentation, and then kind of 'unfold it back'.
2) The $c_{s_i} = q-1$ and $q_s = q$ (mod sign) in the $\mathrm{GL}_n$-case, right? (I looked it up but I still don't really know what the Kottwitz morphism is), and hence I also don't know what $\Omega$ is. I would understand it as the 'defect' from to $\mathrm{GL}_n$ to $\mathrm{SL}_n$

Comment: 2)... since $\mathrm{GL}_n$ is not semi-simple but IM give the description for $G$ semi-simple. That's why this 'defect' is generated by
$$
u = \begin{pmatrix}
 & 1  & & \\
& & \ddots & \\
& & & 1 \\
\pi & & & 
 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
This defect has length $0$ right? The length is positive only for non-trivial elements of the affine Weyl Group, right?

Comment: 3) If so far correct, I still struggle then in the conversion. Let us say, I have the element
$$
\pi^{(3,1,0)} = \begin{pmatrix}
  \pi^{3} & & \\
  & \pi^{1} & \\
& & 1
 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
How do I get the reduced expression for this $\pi^{\lambda}$ methodically?

Comment: i) Since $\det(\pi^{(3,1,0)}) = \pi^4$, I would try to multiply it (from the right) by $u^{-4}$ and hence, I should end up in the affine Weyl group. 
ii) Then I would look for some $w$ in the (finite) Weyl group, that brings me the resulting element on a diagonal form, which would be than the affine part.
iii) The $w$ I would then be expressed as a product of simple reflections.
iv) But here I am kind of stuck. How would I know, that this is a reduced expression? In fact, I don't.
v) If possible, I would work out the example above and come back in a few days.

Comment: To answer some questions: yes, in the Iwahori case, we have $c_s = q - 1$ and $q_s = q$.  Moreover, $\Omega$ is cyclic, generated by the element $u$ you wrote down.  $\Omega$ is a subgroup of the extended affine Weyl group of $\textrm{GL}_n$, and it is exactly the subgroup of elements of length 0.

Comment: To produce reduced expressions takes some practice.  For the example of $\pi^{(3,1,0)}$, you have that the length is 6 (length for diagonal elements is straightforward to compute, cf. Cor. 5.11 in Vigneras' paper).  Moreover since the determinant is $\pi^4$, the reduced expression involves $u^4$.

Comment: One way to try to come up with a reduced expression is to find expressions for $\pi^{(1,0,0)}, \pi^{(0,1,0)}, \pi^{(0,0,1)}$, multiply out appropriate powers, and try to do some cancellations with braid relations until you get length 6.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. But I would rather come with reduced expressions for the $\pi^{b_i}$ where
$$
b_i = (1,...,1,0,...,0)
$$
are the fundamental coweights consisting of $1$'s up to the $i$-th position and $0$ afterwards, since they are dominant.

Comment: Ok, so far I got
$$
\pi^{b_1} = s_1s_2 u, \qquad \pi^{b_2} = s_2s_1 u^{2} \qquad (\pi^{b_3} = u^3).
$$
And hence $\pi^{(3,1,0)} = \left(\pi^{b_1}\right)^{2} \cdot \pi^{b_2}$. It should follow that (using that $us_i = s_{i-1}u$ from Cherednik's \textsl{Affine-like Hecke Algebras...}),
\begin{eqnarray*}
\pi^{\lambda} & = & s_1s_2 u \cdot s_1s_2 u \cdot s_2s_1 u^{2} \\
& = & s_1s_2 u \cdot s_1 s_2 s_1s_0 u^{3} \\
& = & s_1s_2 s_0 s_1 s_0s_2 u^{4}.
\end{eqnarray*}
The latter should be now a reduced expression since I got $q(\lambda) = 6$ reflections $s_i$'s, and hence...

Comment: $$
T^{-1}_{\lambda} = q^{-6} \cdot T_{u^{-4}}T^{\ast}_{s_2} \cdot \ldots \cdot T^{\ast}_{s_1},
$$
with each $T^{\ast}_{s_i} = T_{s_i} - (q-1)$. If so, I think I might have understood something.

Comment: Another nuance I don't understand. In her paper, Vigneras states that $c_{s^{-1}} = c_s s^{2}$ and hence for a simple transposition $s$ with $s^{2} = 1$, this should be both $q-1$ (otherwise the quadratic Relation wouldn't be satisfied). But on the contrary, I would need it to be exactly $(q-1)^{-1}$, otherwise it is not what I get in the case for $T^{-1}_{(1,0)}$ I computed at the beginning. (I am not sure about if the second one was $T_{w_2}$, but I am pretty sure about the factor $(q-1)^{-1}$.

Comment: Let $f := T^{-1}_{(1,0)}$. Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
1(x) & = & \int_{\mathrm{GL}_n(F)} f(xy^{-1})T_{(1,0)}(y) dy \\
& = & \int\limits_{J_n \pi^{(1,0)} J_n} f(xy^{-1}) dy \\
& = & \int\limits_{\coprod_{u \in \mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{p} }J_n \begin{pmatrix}
1 & \\
u & 1
\end{pmatrix} \pi^{(1,0)}} f(x y^{-1}) dy \\
& = & \sum_{u \in \mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{p}} f(x  \begin{pmatrix}
\pi^{-1} & \\
 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & \\
u & 1
\end{pmatrix} ).
\end{eqnarray*}
Now for $x = 1 \in J_n$, one has
$$
1 = q \cdot f(\begin{pmatrix}
\pi^{-1} & \\
 & 1
\end{pmatrix}).
$$

Comment: Now for (here $u$ is the generator of $\Omega$)
$$x = u^{-1}\pi^{(1,0)} = \begin{pmatrix} & \pi^{-1} \\ 1 & \end{pmatrix}\pi^{(1,0)} \notin J_2,
$$
one has 
\begin{eqnarray*}
0 & = & f(u^{-1}) + \sum\limits_{t \in (\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{p})^{\times}} f\left(u^{-1}  \begin{pmatrix} 1 &  \\ t & 1 \end{pmatrix} \right) \\
& = &  f(u^{-1}) + \sum\limits_{t \in (\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{p})^{\times}} f\left( \begin{pmatrix} \pi^{-1} & \\ & 1 \end{pmatrix} \right) \\
& = & f(u^{-1}) + (q-1) f(\pi^{(-1,0)}) \\
& = & f(u^{-1}) + \frac{q-1}{q},
\end{eqnarray*}
and now evertyhing makes sense.

Comment: $(\ast)$ In the above I have used that
$$
J_2 u^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \\ t & 1 \end{pmatrix} J_2 = J_2 \pi^{-(1,0)} J_2.
$$